# CRUD Kendo, Batch Update Grid return data null

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have this schema,

```
  schema: {
                    data: "d.Data", // web methods return JSON in the following format { "d": <result> }. Specify how to get the result.
                    total: "d.Total",
                    model: {
```

in transport:

```
update: {
                            url: "VisorEuroProv.aspx/Update", //specify the URL which should create new records. This is the Create method of the Products.asmx service.
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // tells the web method to serialize JSON
                            type: "POST" //use HTTP POST request as the default GET is not allowed for web methods
                            //complete: function(e) {  $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read()} 

                        },
```

and WebMethod

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static void Update(IEnumerable<dtoVisorEuroProveedores> dtoVisorEuroProveedores)
    {...}
```

Update works correctly, but not close BatchEdit, shows javascript error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Data' of null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I return a List() of `IEnumerable< myObject >`variable .

Comment: I have the same issue as described but I don't understand your answer. Please can you add more detail on how you resolved the issue.